# Best way to actually sort a database table with sqlite and in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, sqlite

I need to sort a table permanently. I have no control of how the database is created or its tables. I have a program written in c++ that has several methods that do different things with the database and its tables. For instance print, recall row, update row, download row, update row and the list goes on.

I am currently on sort database. It needs to actually sort the database in respect to a specified column and can be sub sorted by another column if the user specifies one. So that after the sort is done if it was viewed with a third party application for instance all the data would show up sorted.

I know SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2 would return the table sorted but from an actually memory stand point all the data is the table is still the same, so if col 1 was all out of order after the ORDER BY the database viewer would still show col 1 all out of order. After the sort the data in the database should be sorted and when viewed in the database viewer it all be in order.

This is a complete Edit of my first post. fyi

Comment: Why? Don't you use indexes? Smells like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I believe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. What are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: You should create in index in the database on the fields you want to sort by and then use "order by" on those fields and the database will do the sorting. The index *is* exactly the "permanently stored" sort you are looking for unless I misunderstand your *reasons* for needing this.

Comment: Could be the XY problem here sorry about that :/ I cant control how the database is created. For a bit of background the user creates a database on their own and then in the program that database is opened up. I have several different commands that they can execute such as print, recall row, update row, and so on. One of the commands is a sort database. Now this command needs to sort the database based one a column they specify, and can be sub sorted further if they specify a second column. What is the best or a way to achieve this? I am an sqlite novice at best. Could you elaborate on indexes

Comment: Whether you create indexes or not, I would [create a view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) based on the user's choices and then use that as the data source. Creating indexes on sort columns will speed up the performance.

Comment: "I cant control how the database is created... One of the commands is a sort database." - Sounds like an exercise in creating the queries required to output the sorted data. Certainly you wouldn't modify the database if you don't own it, you would present the data to the user in the way they want it... so I think you want dynamic queries (select ... from order by A,B,C (A,B,C - based on input)

Comment: @RogerRowland I think there is a chance creating this view could work and actually quite well. Could you elaborate or suggest how it could work for me according to what I wrote in the comment to Caribou.

Comment: @Caribou I want to actually modify the database unless present with some other idea to solve my problem.

Say the user sorts the data. Then a few lines down decides they want to update a row or add a new one. Say they update a row in the middle and change the columns value that they just previously sorted on. Or if they add a new row and that columns value isn't in order. Either way when they print it out it should be all in order except for the value they just changed.

Comment: If I insert a row into the database table (anywhere) the result of the 'select' when used with 'order by' will be sorted without you doing anything. The print function will just call that query, and the user selecting sort columns updates that query to order arbitrarily.

Comment: @Caribou Sorry to confuse you. The print doesn't print out the database via a ORDER BY query. It prints it out row by row as the data is stored in the database. I know this doesn't make sense as a good set up or system but it is what I am stuck writing an interface for.

Comment: @RogerRowland Does what I'm about to present to you make sense and seem to be a seemingly appear to be a quick process? Step 1) Create View of sorted table via SELECT ORDER BY. Step 2) Create a table with the same properties of the old table via found through a PRAGMA table_info. Step 3) INSERT INTO newTable SELECT col1,col2,.. FROM theView

Seems logical to me but I am not really sure I guess unless there is a way to just replace the original table data with the view?

Comment: "I know this doesn't make sense as a good set up or system but it is what I am stuck writing an interface for" - Sorry I was fixated and didn't reread your question. You either do it via a second table like your own suggestion, or you pull it into say a C++ vector via the select then delete the rows in the table and re insert from the vector. (second way would require you to consider the size of the data set and handle callbacks etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the help of @RogerRowland I was able to solve this issue but for those looking to do the same thing as me. Why you would actually ever want to do this I dont know, but if you need to actually sort the database table's data rather than just return sorted data and are using sqlite3 and c++ this is what you wanna do.

Step 1)

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare(this->dbPointer, "CREATE [TEMP] VIEW tempViewOfSortedTable AS SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName", -1, &ppStmt, NULL);
```

Step 2)
Grab all of your table info (column name and types and what not) and store it in a string with.

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(this->dbPointer, "pragma table_info tableName", -1, &ppStmt, NULL);
```

Step 3) Create a new table with the same columns and properties as your original.

```
sprintf(strQuery, "CREATE TABLE tempUserTable (%s)", strListOfFieldsAndTypes);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK)rc = sqlite3_exec (this->dbPointer, strQuery, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

Step 4) Copy all of your view's sorted data into the new table.

```
sprintf(strQuery, "INSERT INTO tempUserTable SELECT %s FROM tempViewOfSortedTable", strListOfFields);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK)rc = sqlite3_exec (this->dbPointer, strQuery, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

Step 5) Drop the old table

```
if (rc == SQLITE_OK)rc = sqlite3_exec (this->dbPointer, "DROP TABLE tableName", NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

Step 6) Rename your new table to the old name if desired.

```
if (rc == SQLITE_OK)rc = sqlite3_exec (this->dbPointer, "ALTER TABLE tempUserTable RENAME TO 'tableName'", NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

You may also want to drop the view if you didn't create a temp one or even if you are going to be repeating this before you close the db because if you dont the temp view lasts till you close the db.

Also by all means not claiming this is the fast route. The only reason I was using sqlite3_exec is because I recycled someone else's old code I will be replacing it with sqlite3_prepare_v2 myself but wanted to get this up for any others with the same question.

Sources.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html